# C# How to solve this dilema with optional arguments in method?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, generics, nullable

I have a db structure (Entity Framework Model) which looks something like that:

*`Business <-1----*-> Users <-*----0..1-> Role`*

Very simple and straightforward:
a business can have users.
a user must belong to a business.
a user may or may not relate to a role.
a role can relate to many users.

in the API level of the server I'd like to implement functionality that would allow the following method services:

```
//get all users
List<User> GetUsers();

//get all users belong to a business
List<User> GetUsers(int businessId);

//get all users with specific role
List<User> GetUsers(int roleId);

//get all users belong to a business with specific role
List<User> GetUsers(int businessId, int roleId);
```

But I do not wish to write 4 overloads to what I'd like to write in just a single method with optional parameters/named arguments, So
Instead of those 4 I'd like to create the following service method:

```
List<Users> GetUsers(
    int?? businessId=undefined, int?? roleId=undefined)
{
   var queryResult = new List<users>();

   if(!businessId.IsUndefined)
    queryResult= {get from db all business according to Id.}

   if(!roleId.IsUndefined)
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(item=>user.role.Id==roleId)
}
```

And now you wonder what's with the **"??"** thingy..

well, let's assume I want to get all users which has 0 relation to roles. - this would return a specific criteria.

now, let's assume I want to get all users regardless of role relation. - this would return a different criteria.

But named argument can be only Nullable to support that behavior:

```
List<Users> GetUsers(int? RoleId=null)
{
// is this null becuase it was not specified or is it null because
// it was called with null as argument.
// I need to know the difference to give the correct criteria.
// But I cannot tell the difference from within here...
// as in here it is simply null or some value.
}
```

So here comes a solution, I want an int to be not just nullable,
I also want it to be undefinable.. and I would be able to set a method as follows:

```
List<Users> GetUsers(int?? RoleId=undefined)
```

So an **int??** would be to be any of those examples:

int?? x = undefined;

int?? x = null;

int?? x= 5;

The question is - is that possible?
Can I create somthing that would allow "int??" definition...

If so - how do I do that?
If not - how to overcome this problem?

Comment: `Nullable<T>` either has value (non-null value) or does not have value (null). There is no third state you could use. You'd have to create your own version of `Nullable`, call it `NullableOrUndefined` and use instead of `Nullable<T>`. Or you can use negative number to represent `undefined`, but only if there is no way you have a valid `RoleId` with negative value.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yeah, I'm in that direction but how do I tell C# that int?? would mean that? I don't find anything in `nullable` that tells `?` means nullable.

Comment: It's part of C#, and you cannot make it work with your own type. `int?` is just a syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>`, and it's described in C# specification.

Comment: So I take it there is not way to create another synthetic sugar for `??`. Ok that is progress :) examining McGarnagle answer which looks a continue to your suggestion.

Comment: Even if it were possible to add a third state to nullable, I wouldn't recommend it.  I tremble at the confusion I'd feel if I had to use an API that had one function and nine (!) different meanings based on two parameters.

Bite the bullet and write your overloads, or better yet, write different methods with different names.

Comment: @Ben yeah I hear you.. but I also tremble to implement per each service method many overloads - consider the users is just one entity and I have 18 more of those... some relate to 7 other entities.. you get the picture :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use wrapper classes for "business" and "role", but define implicit type conversions.  These type conversions would allow your API users to send you either an `int`, or a `Role.Undefined`, or then null.

So the Role class for example would look something like this:

```
public class Role
{
    private bool _isUndefined;
    private int _val;

    private Role()
    {
        _isUndefined = true;
    }

    private Role(int val)
    {
        _val = val;
    }

    public static Role Undefined
    {
        get { return new Role(); }
    }

    public static implicit operator Role(int val)
    {
        return new Role(val);
    }
}
```

Then your signature would look like this:

```
List<User> GetUsers(Business business = null, Role role = null);
```

And your users could call it like:

```
GetUsers(Business.Undefined, Role.Undefined);
```

Or

```
GetUsers(1, 2);
```

Or

```
GetUsers(role: 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

After very deep investigation of the problem and considering the accepted answer carefully,
I decided to go for the code architecture which I believe is the best one now.

I still would like to keep McGarnagle answer as the accepted answer to my question as it is an answer to the raw question itself - however I would not recommend it as a solution to the problem I described due to architectural inconsistency between the entity framework model and the service methods.

I recommend using this instead, however if anyone ever need code for `undefined` in different cases I would recommended considering McGarnagle implementation to achieve it.

```
internal class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetUsers();  //get users - all of them - from all businesses - disregard any constrain.
        GetUsers(1);          //get users - which belong to business 1, not matter which role.
        GetUsers(1, null);    //get users - which belong to business 1 and have no assinged role.
        GetUsers(roleId: 3);  //get users - from all business which relate to role 3.
        GetUsers(null, null); //syntax error - business cannot be null! (the big benefit)
        GetUsers(1, 3);       //get users - which belong to business 1 and relate to role 3.
    }

    public static List<User> GetUsers(
                     int businessId = int.MinValue, int? roleId = int.MinValue)
    {
        //int.MinValue - to be considered as undefined.
        //this is the only way to keep consistency with the model abstraction.

        //can make a chain query here.
        //q1 = select according to business or just bring from all businesses.

        //q2 = q1. Select according to roleId..

        //and so on if more parameters involved..

        //return final query result.
    }

}
```